# JQuery Age calculation on date

Tags: jquery

Am I missing something in the following jQuery code?

```
var dob = $('#date').val();
if(dob != ''){
    var today = new Date();
    var dayDiff = Math.ceil(today - dob) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
    var age = parseInt(dayDiff);
    $('#age').html(age+' years old');
}
```

I am getting the pre-fetched value of #date from MySQL db.

```
<input type="text" value="1988-04-07" id="#date" name="dob" /><p id="age"></p>
```

It's returning NaN, not the correct value.

Comment: No, it's probably returning `NaN`, which stands for "Not a Number".

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`$('#date').val()` returns the string `'1988-04-07'`. You need to parse it into an actual number.

```
dob = new Date(dob);
var today = new Date();
var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
$('#age').html(age+' years old');
```

As @esqew points out, you also need to change `id="#date"` to `id="date"`.

Comment: @matt-ball `dob = new Date(dob); ` this conversion is not workng for me if the day number is greater than 12 .. ?? why is that.. can you help me to solve this ????

Answer (score 4):

```
function getAge(dateString) {
  var now = new Date();
 
  var yearNow = now.getFullYear();
  var monthNow = now.getMonth();
  var dateNow = now.getDate();
 //date must be mm/dd/yyyy
  var dob = new Date(dateString.substring(6,10),
                     dateString.substring(0,2)-1,                   
                     dateString.substring(3,5)                  
                     );
 
  var yearDob = dob.getFullYear();
  var monthDob = dob.getMonth();
  var dateDob = dob.getDate();
  var age = {};
  var ageString = "";
  var yearString = "";
  var monthString = "";
  var dayString = "";
 
 
  yearAge = yearNow - yearDob;
 
  if (monthNow >= monthDob)
    var monthAge = monthNow - monthDob;
  else {
    yearAge--;
    var monthAge = 12 + monthNow -monthDob;
  }
 
  if (dateNow >= dateDob)
    var dateAge = dateNow - dateDob;
  else {
    monthAge--;
    var dateAge = 31 + dateNow - dateDob;
 
    if (monthAge < 0) {
      monthAge = 11;
      yearAge--;
    }
  }
 
  age = {
      years: yearAge,
      months: monthAge,
      days: dateAge
      };
 
  if ( age.years > 1 ) yearString = " years";
  else yearString = " year";
  if ( age.months> 1 ) monthString = " months";
  else monthString = " month";
  if ( age.days > 1 ) dayString = " days";
  else dayString = " day";
 
 
  if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + ", " + age.months + monthString + ", and " + age.days + dayString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = "Only " + age.days + dayString + " old!";
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days == 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + " old. Happy Birthday!!";
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days == 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + " and " + age.months + monthString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.months + monthString + " and " + age.days + dayString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + " and " + age.days + dayString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days == 0) )
    ageString = age.months + monthString + " old.";
  else ageString = "Oops! Could not calculate age!";
 
  return ageString;
}
 
// A bit of jQuery to call the getAge() function and update the page...
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitDate").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
 
    $("#age").html(getAge($("input#date").val()));
 
  });
});

and HTML IS
```

Comment: var yearDob = dob.getYear();
should be
 var yearDob = dob.getFullYear();

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the id mentioned in the textbox should not contain '#'

I have also Created  a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNGug/)

Oops i had't checked the date it was posted on

Answer (score 1):

That's what worked for me while all the rest gave NaN:

That only works if the dob format is **mm/dd/yy**

```
function getAge(dob) { return ~~((new Date()-new Date(dob))/(31556952000)) }
$("#dob").val()
$(dob).change(function(){
  $('.age').val(getAge($(this).val()));
});
```

Please see my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A888/98c21nbz/1/

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate age by using moment.min.js.
In HTML file, Please add below line

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Js Code:

```
var dob = $('#date').val();
if(dob != ''){
    var age = moment().diff(moment(dob, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'years');
    $('#age').html(age+' years old');
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#dob").change(function(){

    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date($('#dob').val());
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
   return $('#age').html(age+' years old');
});
```

It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
 jQuery("#dob").on('change',function(){
       var dob1 = jQuery(this).val();
       var dob = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(dob1));
       var str = dob.split('-');    
       var firstdate=new Date(str[0],str[1],str[2]);
       var today = new Date();        
       var dayDiff = Math.ceil(today.getTime() - firstdate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
       var age = parseInt(dayDiff);
       jQuery("#age").html(age+' years old');
   });




<input type="text" id="#dob" class="datepicker" name="dob" /><p id="age"></p>
```