# real time computation of age and display it on input text box

Tags: php, datetime

Hi all I have a time difference formula which work perfectly on back-end but when i run the page the input textbox will disappear/will not display on page.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<?php

$currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
$currenttime = date("h:m:s");
$oDateNow = new DateTime($currentdate);
$oDateBirth = new DateTime($getbirthdate);
$age = $oDateNow->diff($oDateBirth);
?>

<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo "$age";?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">

</div>
```

When I remove the formula the input textbox will display.

The situation is, when the user select the birthdate, age will automatically display on input textbox which is the input textbox is just below the birthdate.

Comment: I think you should do this in `javascript` not `php`.

Comment: @Indrasinh Bihola, Can I ask your help on that.

Comment: I agree with @IndrasinhBihola. There's no reason to use `php` in this case unless you need to save it to a database as well. Have you considdered using [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)? It allows the user to simply select their birthdate. All you have to do is calculate the age.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Age calculation on date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524743/jquery-age-calculation-on-date)

Comment: Just keep in mind doing it client side may result in a different value unless you use something global (utc?). You already have the logic, may be easier to expose this as an ajax endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript**
Put this between your `<head></head>` elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function getAge(){
    var dob = document.getElementById('date').value;
    dob = new Date(dob);
    var today = new Date();
    var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (365.25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    document.getElementById('age').value=age;
}

</script>
```

**HTML**
Put these in your `<body></body>` elements:

```
Put birthdate: <input type="text" value="" id="date" name="dob" onblur="getAge();" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" /><br />
Your age: <input type="text" id="age" name="age" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
```

As soon as the visitor loses focus on the date element, the age will be updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot @icecub, it works. You have such a good heart. May God Bless you always.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$age = $oDateNow->diff($oDateBirth);` is providing following output:

```
 DateInterval Object ( [y] => 26 [m] => 11 [d] => 26 [h] => 0 [i] => 0 [s] => 0 [weekday] => 0 [weekday_behavior] => 0 [first_last_day_of] => 0 [invert] => 1 [days] => 9857 [special_type] => 0 [special_amount] => 0 [have_weekday_relative] => 0 [have_special_relative] => 0 )
```

As you can see, its an array of object.
So You can not `echo` that.

If you want to find Age in php then you can do that in following way.

```
<?php
// $currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
// $currenttime = date("h:m:s");
// $oDateNow = new DateTime($currentdate);
// $oDateBirth = new DateTime($getbirthdate);
// $age = $oDateNow->diff($oDateBirth);

$bday = new DateTime($getbirthdate);
$today = new DateTime(); // use this for the current date
$diff = $today->diff($bday);

//printf('%d years, %d month, %d days', $diff->y, $diff->m, $diff->d);

?>
<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo "$diff->y";?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
```

If you want to see demo for **JavaScript** please [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/bw29n5az/)

Comment: @A. P. when I add this  ' ->y' the age display is zero.

Comment: when I assign a date value on $getbirthdate = '2010-10-12'; it works. But on the page, when the user select a date, there were no computation works that will display on the same page.

Comment: i mean real time display right after the user select a date. the display is zero.

Comment: Remo in that case you can not use php. Please go for Javascript/Jquery. Let me update answer accordingly.

Comment: @Romeo Of course not! The data must be send to the server before PHP can use it. If you want to display it directly, you need to use Javascript instead. Either calculate it completely with Javascript, or use Ajax to retrieve the value from your php script without refreshing the page.

Comment: Thanks A.P. that would be a great help. @icecube thanks - am not that familiar with javascript and Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

`$age` is a Datetime object. To retreive the string version you need to do something like this.

```
$age->format('%a days');
```

so your input field would be

```
<input type="text" name="age" value="<?php echo $age->format('%a days');?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
```

Comment: `Format` is available from PHP 5.3.0. [http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php]
For PHP version lesser than 5.3.0, We can try something like this.

`$getbirthdate_str = strtotime("2014-10-01");
$oDateNow_str = time();
$age_str = $oDateNow_str - $getbirthdate_str;
echo "AGE : " . round($age_str / (60 * 60 * 24));`