# Convert birthdate to age Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this code :

```js
$('.date span').each(function(){
  var date_search =  $(this).text();

  var birthdate_search = new Date(date_search);
  var cur_search = new Date();
  var diff_search = cur-birthdate_search;
  var age_search = Math.floor(diff/31536000000);

  $(this).text(age_search+" years old");

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date">
  <span>05/08/1993</span>
 </div>
<div class="date">
  <span>05/08/1996</span>
 </div>
```

I'm trying to convert the birthdate in each `<div>` to the actual age (birthdate is in `1993` -> `22 years old`), but it does not work.

Comment: Be more detailed about "doesn't work". Errors? Warnings? Freezes? Wrong output?

Comment: Its because you are using variables you don't define like `cur` and `diff`. https://jsfiddle.net/42kqwaa8/

Comment: Hit f12 in your browser and look at the console. Not that you really need that, you are clearly using the wrong variable names.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5524786/1151741

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Age calculation on date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524743/jquery-age-calculation-on-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `cur` and `diff` and you meant to use `cur_search` and `diff_search`.

```
var birthdate_search = new Date(date_search);
var cur_search = new Date();
var diff_search = cur_search - birthdate_search;        // <- here
var age_search = Math.floor(diff_search / 31536000000); // <- here
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a clear simple and easy way to get age. Uses basic math and is super quick. Also, the method itself requires only a basic date string, just like you'd use with `Date` object. Thus it's super easy to use with almost any `datepicker` type plugin.

```
function getAge(bdate) {
  return ~~((new Date() - new Date(bdate)) / (60*60*24*365.2425*1000))
}
```

See ease of use with [jQuery UI datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) below!

```js
function getAge(bdate) { return ~~((new Date()-new Date(bdate))/(31556952000)) }
$("#inpBirthDate").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  defaultDate: '7/5/1980',
  yearRange: '1950:2010'
})
.on('change', function(e) {
  $('#inpAge').val(getAge($(this).val()));
});
```

```css
#inpAge {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="inpBirthDate">Birth Date</label>
<input type="text" id="inpBirthDate">
<hr />
<label for="inpAge">Age</label>
<input type="text" id="inpAge" readonly>
```